# Flutter get navigator param in page

Tags: dart, flutter

I have 2 pages PAGE A and PAGE B. I navigate form PAGE A -> PAGE B and do edit some data, or toggle a setting. Now I want to navigate form PAGE B -> PAGE A and also what that a parameter would be send on navigator pop method. Now my question:

How I can access to these parameter in PAGE A?

```
 Navigator.pop(context, this.selectedEquipmentId);
```

Comment: see what `Navigator#push()` method returns

Comment: I tried this, but is not working:               

this.selectedEquipmentId = Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return ExercisesFilterPage(
                      equipments: equipments,
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ) as String;

Comment: because it is a [Future](https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures#the-future-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact you got to return something when you ends PageA. I put you an exemple with a popup to select an adress i made recently, this work exactly the same if this is not a popup.

```
Future<PlacesDetailsResponse> showAdressPicker({@required BuildContext context}) async {
  assert(context != null);
  return await showDialog<PlacesDetailsResponse>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) => AdressPickerComponent(),
  );
}
```

You can send a result from Navigator.pop(...) and get it from PageA

```
Navigator.pop(context, result)
```

Just put anything you want in result, (here i created a class named PlacesDetailsResponse, use yours or just Int, String...).
Now In pageA when you call this

```
showAdressPicker(context: context).then((PlacesDetailsResponse value) {
  //do whatever you want here
  // this fires when PageB call previous to PageA
});
```